# AWS - Virtual Host point to localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, virtualhost, soapui

I have a SOAPUI MockService that works pretty well on local (by that I mean on the AWS machine.). I've done testing on the machine and the service returns the proper XML.
The service is set to respond to localhost:8081

Now I'm trying to access that service from a browser and I can't.

I think I need to map a virtual host(apache) that listens on port 8081 and redirects to the Mock Service. But I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898874/multiples-domains-pointing-to-differents-ports-in-apache-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to open up port 8081 in the [security group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for your instance.