# Using Apache server beside Windows' World Wide Web Publishing Service

Tags: apache, port

I have an old site (oldsite.com) running via World Wide Web Publishing Service on a Windows Server 2003 server. I've just create a new site (newsite.com) using the same server but running through Apache. The old site with its service running on port 80 already so I had to config Apache using port 8080. The problem is now when I publish my new site, the url has to be newsite.com:8080. How can I config Apache so that it can contain no port, just newsite.com?

Comment: What happens with newsite.com? Does it display the old site?

Comment: @LockeDonohoe: if I don't type port 8080 in, it cannot connect to the newsite

Comment: I thought you were trying to do something different. Can you move the other website to Apache or is it a .net app?

Comment: @PanamaJack: It's a .net app running through IIS though. I researched alot but after changing all the current IIS website to listen to specific IPs, somehow there's still a process listening on 0.0.0.0:80 that I can't start Apache now

Comment: @MinhTranDuc Then why did you switch to apache? Just run the new website under IIS as another site and just use [Host Headers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx) and then you can have both sites on port 80.

Comment: My new site is a wordpress site. I make it on local using WAMP server. Now the server I'm pushing my site to is a Windows Server 2003 machine with IIS 6 which will need a lot of work to make it can work with PHP though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just make it work. Although in IIS Manager, there was no website listening on 0.0.0.0:80 but I still had to delete this entry by httpcfg tool. After that Apache can start normally.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know from personal experience and research:
Due to the nature of DNS Records you cannot specify the domain to redirect to an IP address and a port.
If both servers are listening on the same port a request would not know which site to direct to.
As the default port the domain specifies is port 80, any other port must be specified for the request to go to the correct location.
Therefor you cannot have `newsite.com` redirect to the server IP on port 8080, as it can only be directed to the server IP with DNS records. The port must be specified in the URL if it is on a port other than 80.

Edit: I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898874/multiples-domains-pointing-to-differents-ports-in-apache-server?rq=1) post about using a reverse proxy to do something similar to what you have described. Take a look and see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I changed the IP address, but keep apache running on the same server? I tried to listen on port 80, different ip address but apacha cannot start. Seems like it only check for port 80 on the current server

Comment: You won't be able to use two different IP addresses on the same server. If you want to host multiple websites on the same physical machine I would suggest using virtual machines (multiple servers running alongside each other on the same machine).

Comment: I editing the answer to include a method to do something similar to what you have described.

Comment: @LockeDonohoe you definitely can use 2 different IP address on the same server. Apache can listen on multiple IP addresses.

Comment: I did put an additional IP for the server and set IIS and Apache to listen on seperated IP but somehow it doesn't work. The 2 IPs need to be on 2 different adapters or can it be on the same adapter?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two services listening on the same port. You can  change the old site to listen to another port,  set apache to port  80, then use mod_proxy to enable the old site to be accessed from apache using virtualhost