# How to forward a service to a different port in apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, port, virtual, forwarding

I have an ubuntu server with three services, one running on port 8080, one running on port 8181 and apache running on 80.

My question is, is there a way I can "view" the services web interface on port 80, depending on the URL?

Currently I have to access the services by:

service.domain.com:8080
and
service.domain.com:8181

what I want is:

service1.domain.com to access the service on 8080 without having to include the port and
service2.domain.com to access the service on 8181 without having to include the port

is something like this possible? I was thinking there was a way to do it via virtual hosts, but I cannot think of a clear way to phrase my question to be able to google it further.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to this post:

[Multiples domains pointing to differents ports in apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898874/multiples-domains-pointing-to-differents-ports-in-apache-server?rq=1)

Just needed to setup a Reverse Proxy.