# Open a port for Meteor on Fedora Red Hat 24 in VirtualBox

Tags: meteor, port, virtualbox, fedora

I am running Fedora 24 server in a VirtualBox, with Apache running on port 80. I want to open port 3000 so that I can run a Meteor site on the same virtual server.

I have tried using the CLI command `firewall-c md --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent`, and on the surface, this appears to work:

```
#firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
80/tcp
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
success
# systemctl restart firewalld
# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-ports
3000/tcp 80/tcp
```

The Fedora server at 10.0.0.30 reports that the Meteor app is running ...

```
App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

... but when I connect from a browser in the host machine, I get a notification that:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> http://10.0.0.30:3000/ is unreachable.

When I connect to the plain vanilla http://10.0.0.30, the Apache web site is clearly visible.

What can I do to troubleshoot this and to resolve it?

---

EDIT:

`/etc/selinux/config/` looks like this, but even when it is disabled, the  issue is not resolved:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected.
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: Isn't SELinux blocking the access?

Comment: @Jakuje Even when SELinux is disabled (and one reboot later), the problem still exists. Am I wrong in thinking that Meteor creates only tcp traffic?

Comment: I don't know how to fix the problem, but another approach is to set up your apache config with a reverse proxy on a virtual directory, so that 10.0.0.30:80/meteor will be passed through to port 3000 This approach is also good if you want to run several meteor servers, and it completely avoids firewall issues as port 80 is usually allowed without wrestling :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the firewall issue, but now I have a workaround.

Following the suggestion from @MikeKing, and using the advice given by Jsaac [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898957/1927589), I added the following at the end of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` in the Fedora instance running in VirtualBox:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName apache
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName meteor
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I edited the /etc/hosts/ file on the host machine:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
10.0.0.30   apache 
10.0.0.30   meteor
```

Now (on my machine at least) the url http://apache/ opens the site served by Apache and http://meteor/ opens the Meteor app running on port 3000.